# Обработка целочисленной информации

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая ищет среди целых чисел, принадлежащих числовому отрезку [125 256; 125 330], числа, имеющие ровно шесть различных чётных натуральных делителей. Для каждого найденного числа запишите эти шесть делителей в шесть соседних столбцов на экране с новой строки. Делители в строке должны следовать в порядке возрастания.

Например, в диапазоне [2; 48] ровно шесть чётных различных натуральных делителей имеют числа 24, 36 и 40, поэтому для этого диапазона вывод на экране должна содержать следующие значения:

2 4 6 8 12 24

2 4 6 12 18 36

2 4 8 10 20 40

Проблема заключается в том, что в ответе указано 3 строчки:

2 6 18 13918 41754 125262

2 4 8 31322 62644 125288

2 6 18 13922 41766 125298

У меня же выводится только одна:

[2, 62630, 4, 10, 12526, 20]

```
for num in range(125256,125331):
    ldl=[]
    for dl in range(1, round(num**0.5)+1):
        if num%dl==0:
            if dl%2==0:
                ldl.append(dl)
                if dl<num/dl and (num//dl)%2==0:
                    ldl.append(num//dl)
    if len(ldl)==6:
        print(ldl)
```

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что в вашем диапазоне 125256 - 125331 есть более 1 числа у которого ровно 6 четных делителей ? Очень сложно найти черную кошку в темной комнате, особенно если ее там нет

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать так.

```
from collections import deque

def natural_divisor(a, b):
    d = {}
    deque((d.setdefault(number, [number]).append(value) for number in range(a, b + 1, 2)
           for value in range(2, number//2 + 1, 2) if number % value == 0), maxlen=0)
    return {i: j for i, j in d.items() if len(j) == 6}
last_dict = natural_divisor(125256, 125330)
for key, value in last_dict.items():
    print(key, '-', *sorted(value))
```

Вывод:

```
125262 - 2 6 18 13918 41754 125262
125288 - 2 4 8 31322 62644 125288
125298 - 2 6 18 13922 41766 125298
```